# open balls cover function space

Tags: general-topology

**Part A** (which I understand)

If for every $\epsilon>0$, a metric space $X$ can be covered by a finite number of $\epsilon$-balls,

Then every **point** $x\in X$ is inside at least one $\epsilon$-ball.

**Part B** (which I am confused about)

If for every $\epsilon>0$, a continuous function space $C(X,Y)$ can be covered by a finite number of $\epsilon$-balls: $B(f_1,\epsilon),B(f_2,\epsilon),\dots$

Then every **function** $f\in C(X,Y)$ is inside at least one ball $B(f_i,\epsilon)$. I doubt this conclusion because I can imagine a counterexample: $f$ is partly covered by $B(f_i,\epsilon)$ and partly by $B(f_j,\epsilon)$, while neither of them cover $f$ entirely.

Comment: There's not much of a difference between part a and part b, as far as I know. In part a, you're dealing with a metric space; the set of continuous functions from one set to another is a metric space as well. Why do you think your counterexample is correct, in a precise sense?

Comment: The counterexample does not make sense. What do you mean when you say "$f$ is partly covered"? You've turned the function space into a space where $f$ is just a point--it's either in the ball or it's not, there's no other option.

Comment: @Eevee Trainer, as I understand, f is a function. In my mind f is like a curve, so it can be partly covered by one ball and partly by other balls.

Comment: @Joshua P. Swanson, I am confused about why f is a point? f is a function from X to Y, it should look like a curve, so it may be partly covered.

Comment: @whitegreen You seem pretty confused about the metric space structure on $C(X, Y)$. As an intuitive example, you'd expect the real functions $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x+0.01e^{-x^2}$ to be "close". If you defined their "distance" to be $\sup_x |f(x) - g(x)|$, you'd get 0.01. So, $g$ would be within a 0.02-ball of $f$. You should probably reread whatever introduction to $C(X, Y)$ you've been going through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "counterexample" is nonsense: $B(f_i, \varepsilon)$ is a set of functions and a function is in it or not. You cannot be "partially" in it.

On an abstract level **B** is the same as **A**. It's just about points and sets of points that form a cover of the space they are points from. The fact that the points in **B** are functions internally does not change that at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! $f_i$, the center of $B(f_i, \epsilon)$, is a function. So I am not sure whether $B(f_i, \epsilon)$ is defined on space Y, or on the function space C(X, Y). If it's defined on Y, then $f_i$ is a point; if it's defined on C(X, Y), then $f_i$ is a curve.

Comment: @whitegreen it’s defined on $C(X,Y)$. A ball in $Y$ would be $B(f_i(x), r)$ e.g.